# Technical question in how to correspond operators to dynamical variables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra, observables

I have following question.
Here is the book I use for QM. I understand so far until the step of 3.43.
Can somebody tell me how he arrived at the step of 3.43? I tried to expand the eigenvector in 3.42 with eigenvector of 3.36, But I just couldn't arrive at this expression in 3.43.
A hint is much appreciated.

> We assume the *position operator* for the particle to be $\mathbf{Q} = (Q_1, Q_2, Q_3)$, where by definition
> $$Q_{\alpha}|\mathbf{x}\rangle = x_{\alpha}|\mathbf{x}\rangle \quad (\alpha=1,2,3) \tag{3.36}$$

> $$Q'_{\alpha}|\mathbf{x}\rangle' = x_{\alpha}|\mathbf{x}\rangle' \quad (\alpha=1,2,3). \tag{3.42}$$
> But since $|\mathbf{x}\rangle' = |\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{a}\rangle$, a comparison of (3.42) with (3.36) implies that
> $$\mathbf{Q'} = \mathbf{Q} - \mathbf{a} I. \tag{3.43}$$

Comment: In the future, please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/168783), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) instead. I have edited your post to conform to these standards

Comment: Which book, author, etc..?! What is the context of this question?

Comment: To Tobias:

Ballentine: Modern development of quantum mechanics
Context is how to correspond dynamical variables with operators from one-parameter group. But that question itself just deals with Operator and Transformed Operator and states.

Answer (score 1):

Start from the action of $Q_a'$ on the primed states
$$
Q_a' | \mathbf{x} \rangle ' = x_a | \mathbf{x}\rangle'
$$
Using definition of $|\mathbf{x}\rangle'=|\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{a}\rangle$, we can rewrite that in terms of unprimed states as
$$
Q_a' | \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{a} \rangle = x_a | \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{a}\rangle
$$
Finally, note that $Q_a - \mathbf{a} I$ has the same action as $Q_a'$ on these states
$$
\left(Q_a - \mathbf{a} I\right) | \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{a} \rangle = (x_a + a_a - a_a) | \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{a}\rangle = x_a | \mathbf{x}+\mathbf{a}\rangle
$$
Since $Q_a'$ and $Q_a-\mathbf{a}I$ act in the same way on all states in a complete basis (the position basis), they are equal as operators.